# Angular 2 route not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have created an angular 2 application using CLI, I'm just learning about it, I'm trying to setup a route but for some reason it's not working, when the link is clicked the url is being displayed correctly but the html content is the same, the content of the component I want to display is not being displayed...

This is the app.module.ts code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from '../products/product-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([
          { path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent }
      ])
    ],
  declarations: [
      AppComponent, ProductListComponent
  ],
  //providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is the code of my `product-list.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    template: '<p>Component product list</p>'
})

export class ProductListComponent {
 title: 'The Products from Component...';
}
```

I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong, there are not errors in the Developers Tools Console, there is not any http request made when the link is clicked...

The link I'm talking about is in `app.component.html`:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<p>This is a test</p>
<a [routerLink] ="['/products']"> Values list</a>
```

The main url is this one: `http://localhost:4200`, and when the link is clicked it changes to `http://localhost:4200/products` but just the url changes not the html, the content of the `product-list.component.ts` is not being displayed.. any idea? Do I have any way to find out what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be missing the `router-outlet` directive in your .html.

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<p>This is a test</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<a [routerLink] ="['/products']"> Values list</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Deborah, I've seen your video tutorial in Pluralsight  "Angular : Getting Started" and is great!!! :)

Comment: Thanks! I also have one on routing if you want more info on that: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents

Comment: Thanks! I'll watch it for sure! :)